# Karate multipart field; possible to pass in function?

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I have some test cases where I need to upload a file and can give it a name.  To cut down on time, what I want to do is upload the same file multiple times, but randomly generate a name for it with every pass.

What I have so far for a scenario:

```
* def randomFile =
"""
function randString(length,chars) { 
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}
"""
* def getFilename = randomFile(6, "abcdefgh")

Given url
And request ''
And multipart fields { "profile": "Smoke Test Uploads", "filename": getFilename, "url": "https://s3.file.foo.bar" }
When method post
Then status 201
```

When I look at my uploaded file, it has the filename `getFilename`

Is it possible for me to call a function within a post request like this, or some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [karate embedded expression](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions)

```
And string getFilename = java.util.UUID.randomUUID()
And multipart fields { "profile": "Smoke Test Uploads", "filename": #(getFilename), "url": "https://s3.file.foo.bar" }
```

> Note: UUID.randomUUID() gives you a more convenient way of generating random
>   filenames, if this didn't work you can use your custom js function itself

Comment: Got this working with my custom function!  Only change I had to make based off your suggestion was to wrap it in quotes first using `'#(getFilename)'`.  Interestingly, when I try to do this as a single multipart field it doesn't work

Comment: for a single filed value you can simply call it as a js function, `And multipart field filename = getFilename()`

Comment: OH.  That makes sense now after seeing/playing around with it more.  Thanks!